# expo - react native - web | mobile . Looking for Map implementation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am building a product using expo, a common code base for mobile as well as web. I need to implement a map. Can you please suggest to me the correct npm package or any document to use open street map API. or any other system?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the maps without any direction feature, then you could use [react-native-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps).

If you want to show maps with direction feature, you would use [react-native-maps-direction](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions). But you'll need to provide google api key to use it.